# define an event for DataGridViewColumn ReadOnly property

Tags: c#, datagridview, event-handling, datagridviewcolumn, custom-properties

I have a DataGridView with some columns and I change their ReadOnly property values programmatically. But I need an event which will rise (or give me a chance to do whatever I want) when this value changes. Now I have two questions:

1- Could I define a custom property based on this property?
2- Could I define an event based on property change? (I mean this property)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an event for ReadOnly changed in datagridview.

Comment: No, I know there is a ReadOnly Changed event for DataGridView itself, but I mean the Columns.

Answer (score 0):

To know state change for a particular column use `ColumnStateChanged` event. Use the event argument to check whether the state change is for `ReadOnly` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnstatechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx